# By which vs In Which

Tags: prepositions, relative-pronouns

Sentence:

> Students in the literature course will explore ways in which medieval authors represented themes of their time.

I think substituting "in which" with ***by which*** would be better for the sentence because the sentence talks about methods and ways. Why isn't "by which" a better choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the preposition is determined by the entity to which *which* refers, *ways*. We usually employ different prepositions with different sorts of object. For instance:

> Mediaeval authors represented themes of their times ***through*** established narrative **conventions**.
>   Mediaeval authors represented themes of their times ***by*** **manipulating** audience expectations.
>   Mediaeval authors represented themes of their times ***with*** stock **stories** and **characters**.
>   Mediaeval authors represented themes of their times ***through*** often very subtle deviations from conventional patterns.

These are tendencies rather than rules; but some of them are very strong. *Method* and *means*, for instance, almost always take *by*:

> ***By*** this method Chretien achieves an unprecedented structural clarity.
>   Chaucer's deepest effects are effected ***by*** this means.

*Way* on the other hand almost always takes **in**:

> Mediaeval authors represented themes of their times ***in*** many ways.
>   Chretien structured romantic narrative **in** a **way** for which there is no precedent in earlier analogues.

Since in this case *which* refers to *ways*, the appropriate preposition is *in*:

> ... will explore ***ways in which*** ... *because authors represent themes **in** ways*

If it were *methods*, *by* would be more appropriate:

> ... will explore ***methods by which*** ... *because authors represent themes **by** methods*

Comment: Thanks, should I memorize these rules?

Comment: @Ben As I said, they're tendencies not rules; but you should watch for what preopositions are used with each noun you learn.