# by which or in which?

Tags: prepositions, relative-pronouns

I have a doubt about this sentence:

> Othering is a binary process between the colonizer and colonized **by which** the former is able to affirm his own identity, but the last is considered as the other

I'm confused about the use of "by which". Is it correct? 
If there are any errors in the sentence please tell me.

Comment: Something of your interest [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31583/by-which-vs-in-which) and [here](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090213140119AAKYv9b)

Comment: Are you a colonizer?  No?  But you seem to be "othering" colonizers.  The entire sentence is wrong.

Comment: @jasper why is the whole sentence wrong? Other than possibly the last being the latter it seems fine.

Comment: I agree with @DRF. "Last" should be "latter", but other than that the sentence is completely correct.

Answer (score 10):

"A process by which" describes the *effect* of the process. "A process in which" describes what happens *in* the process.

For example:

> Steeping is a **process by which** tea is made.

In other words:

> Tea is made **by the process** of steeping.

On the other hand:

> Steeping is a **process in which** water absorbs flavor from tea leaves.

Means:

> **In the process** of steeping, water absorbs flavor from tea leaves.

There is often some overlap between these uses, i.e. there are cases in which either is grammatically correct. This is because what happens in a process and what the process does are not clearly distinct. The choice of one or the other can change the connotation of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to interpret the meaning of a sentence which uses by which is replacing the part comes before the by which with "which" . something like this

Othering is a binary process between the colonizer and colonized by which the former is able to affirm his own identity, but the last is considered as the other

by "a binary process" the former is able to affirm his own identity, but the last is considered as the other

Note that I didn't use othering, is, between the colonizer and colonized  because respectively it's the subject of the sentence, is the auxiliary verb (do, does, is , has have, am are etc..), the rest just extends the meaning.