# by which or in which in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, relative-pronouns

I have read a weird selection question on preposition:

> "September 30 is the day ___ which you must pay your bill".

The four given options are:

> A.by.  B.for   C.with   D.in

I cross the options of B and C easily, but not sure whether A or D is the correct/better one to choose.

I have read the previous question of "in which or by which", [q1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31583/by-which-vs-in-which) and [q2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73763/by-which-or-in-which?newreg=bae736011e514f969f6b029d5ecf51d2), but neither case with its explanation seem to match with this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about B and C.

*in* is usually used with longer periods like months, years, seasons. In this sense, it's similar to *during*, and doesn't fit semantically.

*by* is the answer. It indicates you must pay **before** or **not later than** the mentioned date.

*on* would also fit if it were an option and the context allowed. In that case, it would mean the only day you must pay your bills on is the 30th of September.